# Vba code to click on 1 to 3 tabs out of 10 tabs on webpage

Tags: vba, selenium

I have a 10 View Contact tabs in webpage. Out off 10 View Contact tabs i want to click on 1 to 3 View Contact tabs.
Below is the vba code which i have try but it click only 1st tab i have no idea how to make for loop for the same.

```vba
driver.FindElementByXPath("(//input[@value='View Contact'])").Click
```

Below is the html code

```html
<input type="button" class="boxOpener btn blue b" style="width: 150px;font-size: 14px;" value="View Contact">
```

Comment: I guess that cliking navigates you into another site.

Comment: Hi MarcinSzaleniec thanks for the reply.No,After clicking it navigates into same site.

Comment: Does the page reload or its a just a view change on same page?

Comment: before you try to make a loop, make sure that you can click on multiple tabs by using code.   just repeat the code that you posted a few times and adjust each line to click a different tab .... do all ten would be best. .... having ten similar lines all in a column will allow you to see a pattern that could be used to build a loop  .... maybe post the ten lines of code needed to click the ten tabs

Comment: Hi Tarun and jsotola tahnks for the reply, Tarun the page does not relod its just a view change on same page.@jsotola each 10 tabs having the same input value.